# PrimeNG pInputTextarea - Placeholder does not appear when [value] attribute is undefined

Tags: html, angular, textarea, primeng

I have a read-only textarea that should display the values of a certain object.

If the object is `undefined`, it will show "undefined" inside the textarea as well instead of the placeholder. I specifically want to use a placeholder instead of returning the values inside my function when the object is undefined. How can I achieve this?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-inputtextarea-demo-vbm6zp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: If you return an empty string from your function, it will show the placeholder instead of the empty string.

Comment: Thanks. But why does an undefined value not show the placeholder?

Comment: change line no `return;` to `return '';`

Comment: I'm not completely certain but it's most likely because of angular's DefaultValueAccessor that's processes the `[value]` attribute. If the value is not null, it'll send that value as is. You can check the code [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/1c49160129b72f23d9bc2e373a6440dc16b63869/packages/forms/src/directives/default_value_accessor.ts#L103)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returns an empty string or `null` instead of `undefined` will show the placeholder value.

```
showSomething(person: Person): string {
  if(!person) {
    return null;
  }
  return person.name + ' ' + person.surname;
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-inputtextarea-demo-282rkv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks, but why exactly does undefined not show the placeholder, but empty string and ```null``` do?

Comment: Hi, I suspect that is the NgControl behavior. If you try `<input [value]="undefined" />`, you will see the text field will be set with the "undefined" word.